# PrintWriter wont write to .txt file

Tags: java, printwriter

I have tried reviewing old threads about this topic but none of the solutions seem to work for me.  I have trying to write to a .txt file named "receipt.txt" but with the following code I am getting nothing.  No file created (and obviously nothing in the file that doesn't exist) no errors just nothing.

```
//Write to File
 String fileName = "receipt.txt";
 try{
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
     writer.println("Thank you for shopping with us");
     writer.println("Name: " + customerName);
     writer.println("Returning Customer: " + previousCustomer );
     writer.println("Phone: " + phoneNumber);
     writer.println("Shirt Type: " + shirtType);
     writer.println("Shirt Color: " + shirtColor);
     writer.println("Shirt Material: " + shirtMaterial);
     writer.println("Item Amount: " + itmAmt);
     writer.println("Total Cost: " + fmt3.format(totalCostMsg));
     writer.close();
     writer.flush();
     System.out.println("Receipt printed");      
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is writen to the file named `fileName`

replace

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("fileName");
```

with

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
```

EDIT:

Apparenttly you are just not looking for the file in wrong place, add the following statement to see where it has bee created:

```
System.out.println(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());
```

Also note that the order of `close`, `flush` is not correct. `flush` should be called first.

Comment: I could just be using it wrong I am not sure.  I added the line but nothing prints to my console.  I just realized the "COMPLETED" does not even print.  Its like this process of writing the file never even begins. Without throwing hundreds of lines up there I am presenting users with a JOptionPane message, they respond, I record it and now I am trying to print it to the file.  Is there some way I have to initiate this PrintWriter?  The file is not on my computer I can even do a search for it and nothing by that name exsists.                 @Aniket Thakur

Comment: @user3537993, You did not say you have a GUI application, in such a case you have no console, so you cannot see what `System.out` is printing, please use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());` and `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Receipt printed");` to output your messages.

Comment: Your a life saver.  That was not why it was not creating the file but it made me look at where my   System.exit(0); was.... I was exiting the system before i got to that portion of the code.   Thank you though for the  getAbsolutePath() Trick that is definitely going in my book of favorites.  Everything works as it should now thank you.  @Aniket Thakur

Answer (score 3):

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("fileName");
```

should be

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
```

as you have already defined

```
String fileName = "receipt.txt";
```

Comment: That was actually just a type I had recently moved "receipt.txt" from within the parenthesis.  Even with this correction it does not seem to create me a file or edit one even if i create a black one. @A4L

Comment: where are you looking for the file? It will be creates in the projects root directory. So if your project is HelloWorld it will be created in HelloWorld directory and not HelloWorl/src dir. Anyway you can give absolute path and retry.